# suds.WebFault: Server raised fault: 'org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid type: employees'

Tags: python, wsdl, netsuite, suds

I am new to netsuite and I have to integrate the netsuite my current application. I have written the following code to login into the netsuite sandbox environment and create a new data entry into the database.

```
from suds.client import Client
import os, time, sys, datetime
import suds
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

NS_HOST = 'https://webservices.sandbox.netsuite.com'
email ='utkarsh.sharma@ABCD.com'
pwd   ='ABCDEFGHI!'
account = "3828138"
NS_ENDPOINT = "2017_1"
NS_ROLE = 25

wsdl = 'https://webservices.sandbox.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2017_1_0/netsuite.wsdl'

client = Client(url=wsdl)
ApplicationInfo = client.factory.create('ns16:ApplicationInfo')
ApplicationInfo.applicationId = "A8C51D62-63FC-42DC-AE13-B1B971F41C47"

client.set_options(location= NS_HOST + "/services/NetSuitePort_" + 
NS_ENDPOINT, soapheaders={'applicationInfo':ApplicationInfo})

passport = client.factory.create('ns4:Passport')
passport.email = email
passport.password = pwd
passport.account = account

loginResponse = client.service.login(passport,_soapheaders=
{'applicationInfo': ApplicationInfo})


print('Login Response: ')
print (loginResponse.status)

recordRef = client.factory.create('ns4:RecordRef')
recordRef._internalId = 123456789
recordRef._type = 'employees'
record = client.service.get(recordRef)
print (record)
```

I can login but while trying to post the data, I am facing the following error.

```
suds.WebFault: Server raised fault: 'org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid type: employees'
```

Any kind of help is welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The record type should be singular.  Try setting `recordRef.type = 'employee'`, not 'employees'.  Record types will usually be the singular version like, `invoice`, `salesorder`, `customer`, `vendor`.